# Any security holes if we create an action inside a cloud flow using the Office 365 service account, which have full permission on the SharePoint site

Tags: office365, power-automate, power-platform

We have created a new cloud flow using a service account which have full permission on the SharePoint site (the service account is defines as the site collection admin). the flow do the following:-

1. the user enters a new item inside a custom list >> define the manager inside a field>>save the form
2. the flow will run automatically upon creating the item >> and the flow will break the item permissions grant the creator read-only and the manager contribute.

so my question, can the any user, login to Power automate >> create a new flow >> reuse the connection created using the service account and modify the item , even if he only have read permission on it ? is this scenario possible? if the answer is yes, then how we can secure it? am asking this as when i connected to the SharePoint list inside the cloud flow, the connection get added under the connection tab, which means it can be re-used by any user (in other words any user can connect to SharePoint using the service account using a new cloud flow),, am i correct and is my concern valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Connections created in Dataverse are linked to an environment and to the user's account. It is not necessary to share them for the execution of flows.

If a basic user login to Power automate, by default he will not see any connection, he can eventually create new ones (depending on licenses).